# In what case is "Venetiarum" in "Patriarchatus Venetiarum"?

Tags: declension, nominativus

Also, is it a noun or an adjective? What's the nominative? 
(moved second question [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1356/same-ending-of-mediolanensis-in-archiepiscopus-mediolanensis-and-archidioec))

Sorry, I'm a total n00b and checked all sorts of declension tables but I just can't figure this one out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Venetiarum* is the genitive plural of the first-declension noun *Venetia, -ae*. *Venetiae, -arum* (plural) is Latin for English *Venice* (singular).

*Patriarchatus Venetiarum* thus means "The Patriarchate of Venice."

Why is *Venetiae* plural? We have a parallel situation in English, since we refer to one country as "The Maldives" (plural). The plural refers in both cases to a group of islands classed as one territory.

My translation of Carl von Czoernig's [*Die alten Völker Oberitaliens*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Vr9xCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA125):

> Since the time of Constantine, this country was no longer called *Venetia* but *Venetiae* in the plural, because of the distinction between *Venetia superior* and *inferior*; in all likelihood the former comprised the mainland area and the latter included the area along the lagoon. The latter was also already in Roman times called *Venetia marittima*. During the time that the Goths, Longabards, and Franks ruled, this country was also called *Venetiae, -arum* in the plural. (pg. 125)

Comment: Ah, thanks, that clears it up. I thought it looks like a plural genetive but since I don't really master the declensions yet and because other dioceses use adjectives I was left totally confused. Obviously didn't know that Venice is plural in Latin. Should have checked [here](http://www.nihilscio.it/Manuali/Lingua%20latina/Verbi/Coniugazione_latino.asp?verbo=venetia%20&lang=EN_) instead of [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Venetia#Latin).

Comment: There are numerous city names that are plural not only in Latin and Greek, but even in English, e.g. Athenae Athens, Thebae Thebes etc.