# Same ending of "Mediolanensis" in "Archiepiscopus Mediolanensis" and "Archidioecesis Mediolanensis"

Tags: declension, gender

Why is the ending of *Mediolanensis* in *Archiepiscopus Mediolanensis* and *Archidioecesis Mediolanensis* the same even though the former noun is masculine and the latter feminine?

Comment: Grammatical genders are "masculine" and "feminine". Natural sexes are "male" and "female". These terms are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two (main) classes of adjectives in Latin:

- Some adjectives use the first declension for feminines (e.g. *Romana*, "Roman") and the second declension for masculines and neuters (e.g. *Romanus* and *Romanum*).
  For adjectives like this masculine forms look different from feminine forms — with the exception of plural dative and ablative.
- Some adjectives use the third declension for all genders (e.g. *Mediolanensis/Mediolanensis/Mediolanense*, "Milanese", for feminine/masculine/neuter).
  For these adjectives masculine and feminine forms look almost always the same.
  The only exception can be in the singular nominative, but only for some adjectives (e.g. *celeris/celer/celere*, "fast", for feminine/masculine/neuter).
  For *Mediolanensis* there is no difference between feminine and masculine.

In short:
**Some adjectives look different in masculine and feminine, some don't.**

This is also true in Romance languages.
In Italian you have the two forms *romana* and *romano* ("Roman") for the two genders (Italian has no neuter) but *milanese* ("Milanese") is both feminine and masculine.

Comment: Thanks. That was a stupid question though. Sorry. I was just so confused by _[Patriarchatus Venetiarum](http://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/in-what-case-is-venetiarum-in-patriarchatus-venetiarum)_ that I started to look up the Latin names of different dioceses and while still trying to figure out if _Venetiarum_ is a noun or an adjective I noticed that _Mediolanensis_ is not inflected either and started to wonder if this couldn't also be some kind of weird noun.

Comment: @PatVen, no problem. Many questions turn out to be silly in retrospect, but that only shows that something became clear or certain and asking the question was a good idea. The question might be at an elementary level, but it doesn't make it stupid or useless.

Comment: +1, as a quick supplement for the curious: *Mediolanensis* means "Milanese"

Answer (score 5):

To supplement Joonas's excellent answer, Latin has five classes of adjectives, which are generally put into two main groups.

- "First/Second Adjectives"

  - "Normal" adjectives: these take the standard endings for the first and second declensions, and look different in all three genders. *Bonus* is one of these: *bonus*, *bona*, *bonum*.
  - "Irregular" adjectives: these are the same as the normal ones, except that the masculine genitive and dative singular use the older endings *-ius* and *-ī* instead of *-ī* and *-ō*. There are only nine of them in the entire language, which are commonly learned with the mnemonic UNUS NAUTA.
- "Third Adjectives": these ones decline like third-declension nouns.

  - One termination: these adjectives look the same in all three genders, like *atrox*, *atrox*, *atrox*. The only gender differences are the standard rules for the neuter (*-ia* in the plural, accusative matches the nominative). Present participles are in this class.
  - Two terminations: these are the most common "third" adjectives. They have one form in the masculine and feminine, and a different form in the neuter, like *omnis*, *omnis*, *omne*. Comparative adjectives also tend to be in this class, like *melior*, *melior*, *melius*.
  - Three terminations: these are the rarest ones. They have different forms in each different gender, and the masculine always ends in *r*, such as *celer*, *celeris*, *celere*.

In this case, you've found a *third two-termination* adjective, so the masculine and feminine look the same.